# Why "does" the Extinction occur?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Why does the Extinction occur?

Can I place "does" in that position?

What is the correct position of *does*?

Comment: Can you place 'does' there? You *must* place it there: "Why the Extinction occur?"  and "Why the Extinction does occur?" are ungrammatical.

Comment: _Why does the Extinction occur?_ is correct. You might consider using _Why Extinction occurs?_. It may be suited as a content title.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh *Why Extinction Occurs* could certainly work as a title but not with the question mark. It would be synonymous with *The Reason That Extinction Occurs*

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a question in English and the verb is anything other than a be-verb, you swap the subject and the auxiliary verb ([subject auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion)):

> the sun will rise at 6:03am - *statement*
> will the sun rise at 6:03am? - *question*

If there is no auxiliary verb, you have to add the auxiliary verb **do** so that you can make a grammatically correct question:

> it rains every day here  - *statement*
> **does** it rain every day here? - question

The same applies when you have a question word:

> it rains every day here  - *statement*
> why **does** it rain every day here? - question

In your sentence, **does** is a dummy auxiliary verb: it is required to make a grammatically correct question, and it must go before the subject, in order to produce a subject-auxiliary inversion.

> Why **does** the Extinction occur?

I am not sure what your sentence means, but that's the explanation of **does**.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, it's correct. I don't know if it is what you mean to ask, since I don't know which extinction you are talking about. I don't know why you've used a capital "E", that might be a mistake, or not. It might be that you wanted to ask about an extinction in the past, or the future, in which it is wrong because you haven't correctly used tense. But grammatically, it is English.

You could use "Why the Extinction does occur" but that is not a question and not a sentence (It is a noun phrase)  There is nowhere else that you can place "does".

Comment: The following "Why the Extinction does occur" is not a question and not a sentence, so, what is that? Is that a following? Why a sentence has "Why" at the beginning is not a question?

Comment: Consider the question "Who is it?"   Now consider the sentence "Tell me who it is."  The phrase "who it is" is not a question and not a sentence, it is a phrase.  For the same reason you could have a question "Why does the extinction occur" and a sentence "Tell me why the extinction occurs".  But "why the extinction does occur" is not a complete sentence and not a question.